# MvcBuildViews not working for x64 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-views

In a VS2017 ASP.NET MVC project I've noticed that my views aren't syntax checked on build/compile even though I have set `MvcBuildViews` to `true`. The project is now on MVC 5 but has been upgraded from some earlier version. It also started out being set to AnyCPU but it's now set to x64 (we need a lot of data in memory sometimes, and we always deploy to x64, so...).

I've checked that the `.csproj` contains the build target that has been mentioned in various places, including several in SO answers. I've tried a few variations, but none has worked.

This is the one that was present but commented out in the `.csproj` when I started investigating:

```xml
<Target Name="BuildViews" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Message Importance="normal" Text="Precompiling views" />
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

If i uncomment it, I get a build error (I've manually translated it from Swedish):

> Failed to read the file or assembly MyProjectName or one of its dependencies. An attempt to read a program with invalid format was made.

File: `C:\...MyProjectPath...\ASPNETCOMPILER`

It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556085/1073313) to specify the x64 ASP.NET compiler:
Add this below the `<MvcBuildViews>` tag:

```xml
<AspNetToolPath Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319</AspNetToolPath>
```

And add attribute `ToolPath="$(AspNetToolPath)"` to the target's `<AspNetCompiler.../>` tag.

Doing so results in another error (again translated by me from Swedish):

> Failed to read the file or assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of its dependencies. The found assembly's manifest definition doesn't match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

File: `C:\temp\global.asax`

The assembly in question is pulled into the project by our use of a Stripe card payment NuGet package, which was added after the project was changed from AnyCPU to x64. The `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` package is installed in version 4.3.0. The `web.config` contains this binding redirect (why don't the version numbers match 4.3.0?):

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

At this point, I'm out of ideas, what to try next. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I did try emptying the `obj` and `bin` folders. It didn't help.

Comment: Hi Kjell, any update about this issue?

Comment: I hope to find time to give it a go today. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: Hope your any feeback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register that dll into GAC:

Try these:

**1)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**2)** open **developer command prompt for VS** as Administrator and then type:

```
cd C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.3.0\lib\net45

gacutil /i System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
```

Also, you can download `system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation` nuget package version `4.0.0`.

**After that**, register that dll under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.0.0\lib\net45`.

Besides, there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487).

Comment: Unfortunately I got stuck at step 1 because the project uses a NuGet package that no longer exists (old bundler) and the new one `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` has known bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067798/system-web-optimization-jsminify-produces-invalid-javascript that took me quite a while to find. Not sure I can waste more time on it, but if/when I do, I will make sure I give feedback/accept your answer.

Comment: Did your issue solve? How is your question going now? If the nuget package did not exist, you should abandon it. And suggestion 2 is what I recommend to you. It should do some work. If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it:)

Comment: Thanks! I did try to abandon the package but got problems with the replacement due to the bug i mentioned. As things stand I can't waste more time on the precompilation issue right now, so I'm afraid it is going to take a while before I can conclude any outcome of your answers. I will update/accept when I eventuelly get there.

Comment: Hope your any feedback in the future.